MAPIE and pytorch
I am trying to get MAPIE conformal intervals (specifically enbpi) to work with a pytorch built FFN, that I want to use for time series modeling. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to wrap the pytorch model in a way that allows it to be used by MAPIE, there is also a complete lack of time series examples with pytorch being wrapped. MAPIE docs do say that they can wrap around MAPIE, but I cannot find an example of this. I make my own attempt (with the help of chatGPT) which was poor and kept encountering shape issues with the data being loaded in and being output. I also attempted to use scorch, but this was unsuccessful too.
I have added data to a github feature request on mapie's github
Any help is appreciated, please see the below.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import lightning as L
from lightning.pytorch.callbacks.early_stopping import EarlyStopping
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


from lightning import Trainer
from lightning.pytorch.callbacks.early_stopping import EarlyStopping
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

gpu_available = torch.cuda.is_available()
device_name = torch.cuda.get_device_name(0) if gpu_available else "CPU"


data = pd.read_csv('data\pseudo_sales.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
data = data.sort_values('date')

def add_datetime_features(df, datetime_column):
    df[datetime_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[datetime_column])
    df['year'] = df[datetime_column].dt.year
    df['month'] = df[datetime_column].dt.month
    df['week'] = df[datetime_column].dt.isocalendar().week
    df['day'] = df[datetime_column].dt.day
    
    return df.copy()

df = add_datetime_features(data, "date")

date_col = df['date'].copy()
features = df.drop(columns=['sales','date']).copy()
target = df['sales'].copy()

# scaling 
feature_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
target_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
features_scaled = feature_scaler.fit_transform(features)
target_scaled = target_scaler.fit_transform(target.values.reshape(-1, 1))

def create_time_windows(features, target, window_size):
    inputs = []
    targets = []
    for i in range(len(features) - window_size):
        inputs.append(features[i:i+window_size])
        targets.append(target[i+window_size])
    return np.array(inputs), np.array(targets)

window_size = 32
inputs, targets = create_time_windows(features_scaled, target_scaled, window_size)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# apply device to tensors and create datasets
class TimeSeriesDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, targets):
        self.inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
        self.targets = torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.inputs[idx], self.targets[idx]
        
        train_size = int(0.6 * len(inputs))
val_size = int(0.2 * len(inputs))
test_size = len(inputs) - train_size - val_size

train_dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(inputs[:train_size], targets[:train_size])
val_dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(inputs[train_size:train_size + val_size], targets[train_size:train_size + val_size])
test_dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(inputs[train_size + val_size:], targets[train_size + val_size:])

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)  # No shuffle for time-series
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

class ffnetwork(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, sequence_length, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, output_dim=1, learning_rate=0.0001, dropout_rate=0.5, activation_func=nn.ReLU()):
        super(ffnetwork, self).__init__()
        
        # Use sequence_length passed to the model to define the first layer
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(input_dim * sequence_length, hidden_dim)])
        
        # Add additional hidden layers
        for _ in range(num_layers - 1):
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
        
        # Define the output layer
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim))
        
        # Additional properties
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.activation = activation_func
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

    def forward(self, x):
        # Flatten the input while preserving the batch size
        batch_size, sequence_length, input_dim = x.size()
        x = x.view(batch_size, sequence_length * input_dim)
        
        # Pass through each layer in the network
        for i in range(len(self.layers) - 1):
            x = self.activation(self.layers[i](x))
            x = self.dropout(x)  # Apply dropout
        
        x = self.layers[-1](x)  # Output layer
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        return optimizer
        
input_dim = inputs.shape[2]  
sequence_length = inputs.shape[1]  
hidden_dim = 63  
num_layers = 4   
output_dim = 1   
learning_rate = 0.000689
dropout_rate = 0.170971


model = ffnetwork(input_dim=input_dim, sequence_length=sequence_length, hidden_dim=hidden_dim,
                  num_layers=num_layers, output_dim=output_dim, learning_rate=learning_rate, dropout_rate=dropout_rate).to(device)
                  
                  early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss',  # Metric to monitor
    patience=50,         # Number of epochs to wait without improvement
    verbose=True,
    mode='min'           # 'min' because we want to minimize the validation loss
)

# Initialise and train
trainer = Trainer(
    accelerator="gpu", devices=1,
    max_epochs=300, 
    callbacks=[early_stopping], 
    logger=True)

trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)

# List to store predictions and actual values
predictions = []
actuals = []

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# back to cpu
device = next(model.parameters()).device

with torch.no_grad():  
    for batch in test_loader:
        inputs, targets = batch
        inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        predictions.extend(outputs.squeeze().numpy())
        actuals.extend(targets.squeeze().numpy())

# backtransform
predictions = target_scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(predictions).reshape(-1, 1))
actuals = target_scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(actuals).reshape(-1, 1))


note. darts are working on a version of conformal intervals, a simple weighting approach and not this. There is also conformal tights for darts, but it only works on probabilistic models. Nixtla have a version which is a simple weighting. The enbpi approach is slow, so slow. If you are only using a few models and you need to use narrow intervals I recommend it. But if you are using it for things like detecting absurd forecasts, then the weighted version works well most of the time.

This was a huge pain, and I am not sure it was correct. The main issue was that I was building an FFN, which requires 3D tensors (window embeddings). If one was using an LSTM, the process may be similar to some extent, as you do not need time embeddings due to the network inherently handling sequences. However, FFN are surprisingly effective, and it's useful to test them.
I had to adjust the network to act like an sklearn model and then addjust some of the underlying functions to fit with the tensor structures i.e. new bootstrapping function. There is also some 'cheating' is going on, as you need training information to build embeddings in the test sets. Tbh alot of NNs with time series forecasting create time embeddings before splitting, this is a data leakage issue. You can get around this by recursively building the windows (slow, btw) and using training data to build the first 'lags'; of course, if the windows are large, this undermines validation, against other models.
Anyhow here is my attempt, which worked for the FFN, but the enbpi adaptive version of conformal intervals did not work for me. And because it was so slow, as its rebuilds the network multiple times, I abandoned it for a simlar weighted approach, which is less accurate but does the job and is better job in production due to reduced computational costs.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset, Dataset
import lightning as L
from lightning import Trainer
from lightning.pytorch.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler, Mapper, BoxCox
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.model_selection._split import _BaseKFold
from typing import Generator, Tuple, Any, Optional, Union
from numpy.typing import NDArray

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Data laod
data = pd.read_csv('data\pseudo_sales.csv')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
data = data.sort_values('date')

# Plot series
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(data['date'], data['sales'], label='sales')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('sales')
plt.title('Sales over time')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Date features
def add_datetime_features(df, datetime_column):
    df[datetime_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[datetime_column])
    # Drop Sunday (value is 6)
    #df = df[df[datetime_column].dt.weekday != 6].copy()
    
    # Features
    df['year'] = df[datetime_column].dt.year
    df['month'] = df[datetime_column].dt.month
    df['week'] = df[datetime_column].dt.isocalendar().week
    df['day'] = df[datetime_column].dt.day    
    return df.copy()

df = add_datetime_features(data, "date")
date_col = df['date'].copy() # useful later 

# Data splitting 
test_size = 7 * 13
df_train = df.iloc[:-test_size, :].copy()
df_test = df.iloc[-test_size:, :].copy()
X_train = df_train.loc[:, ["day_of_week", "week_num", "promotion", "price", "year", "month", "week", "day"]]
y_train = df_train["sales"]
X_test = df_test.loc[:, ["day_of_week", "week_num", "promotion", "price", "year", "month", "week", "day"]]
y_test = df_test["sales"]

class TimeSeriesDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, targets):
        self.inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.targets = torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(-1, 1)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.inputs[idx], self.targets[idx]

class FFNetwork(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, sequence_length, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, output_dim=1, learning_rate=0.0001, dropout_rate=0.5):
        super(FFNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(input_dim * sequence_length, hidden_dim)])
        for _ in range(num_layers - 1):
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim))
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, sequence_length, input_dim = x.size()
        x = x.view(batch_size, sequence_length * input_dim)
        for i in range(len(self.layers) - 1):
            x = self.activation(self.layers[i](x))
            x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.layers[-1](x)
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(y_hat, y)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)

class SKLearnFFNetwork(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, sequence_length, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, output_dim=1, 
                 learning_rate=0.0001, dropout_rate=0.5, batch_size=32, max_epochs=300):
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.max_epochs = max_epochs
        self.model = None
        self.feature_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        self.target_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

    def create_time_windows(self, features, target):
        inputs, targets = [], []
        for i in range(self.sequence_length, len(features)):
            inputs.append(features[i-self.sequence_length:i])
            targets.append(target[i])
        return np.array(inputs), np.array(targets)

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Scale features and target
        X_scaled = self.feature_scaler.fit_transform(X)
        y_scaled = self.target_scaler.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1, 1))

        # Create time windows
        inputs, targets = self.create_time_windows(X_scaled, y_scaled)

        # Create datasets
        train_dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(inputs, targets)
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)

        # Initialise and train model
        self.model = FFNetwork(
            input_dim=self.input_dim,
            sequence_length=self.sequence_length,
            hidden_dim=self.hidden_dim,
            num_layers=self.num_layers,
            output_dim=self.output_dim,
            learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
            dropout_rate=self.dropout_rate
        )

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='train_loss', patience=10, verbose=True, mode='min')
        trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=self.max_epochs, callbacks=[early_stopping], logger=True)
        trainer.fit(self.model, train_loader)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        self.model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            X_scaled = self.feature_scaler.transform(X)
            inputs, _ = self.create_time_windows(X_scaled, np.zeros((X_scaled.shape[0], 1)))
            inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32)
            predictions = self.model(inputs).cpu().numpy()
            predictions = self.target_scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
            return predictions.flatten()

class SKLearnFFNetwork(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, sequence_length, hidden_dim, num_layers=1, output_dim=1, 
                 learning_rate=0.0001, dropout_rate=0.5, batch_size=32, max_epochs=300):
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.max_epochs = max_epochs
        self.model = None
        self.feature_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        self.target_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

    def create_time_windows(self, features, target=None):
        inputs = []
        targets = [] if target is not None else None
        for i in range(len(features) - self.sequence_length + 1):
            inputs.append(features[i:i+self.sequence_length])
            if target is not None:
                targets.append(target[i+self.sequence_length-1])
        return np.array(inputs), np.array(targets) if targets is not None else None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = X.values
        if isinstance(y, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame)):
            y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
        elif isinstance(y, np.ndarray):
            y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

        X_scaled = self.feature_scaler.fit_transform(X)
        y_scaled = self.target_scaler.fit_transform(y)

        inputs, targets = self.create_time_windows(X_scaled, y_scaled)

        train_dataset = TimeSeriesDataset(inputs, targets)
        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)

        self.model = FFNetwork(
            input_dim=self.input_dim,
            sequence_length=self.sequence_length,
            hidden_dim=self.hidden_dim,
            num_layers=self.num_layers,
            output_dim=self.output_dim,
            learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
            dropout_rate=self.dropout_rate
        )

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='train_loss', patience=10, verbose=True, mode='min')
        trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=self.max_epochs, callbacks=[early_stopping], logger=True)
        trainer.fit(self.model, train_loader)

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        self.model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
                X = X.values
            X_scaled = self.feature_scaler.transform(X)
            inputs, _ = self.create_time_windows(X_scaled)
            inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32)
            predictions = self.model(inputs).cpu().numpy()
            predictions = self.target_scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
            
            # Pad predictions to match original input length
            padded_predictions = np.full(X.shape[0], np.nan)
            padded_predictions[self.sequence_length-1:] = predictions.flatten()
            return padded_predictions

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {
            "input_dim": self.input_dim,
            "sequence_length": self.sequence_length,
            "hidden_dim": self.hidden_dim,
            "num_layers": self.num_layers,
            "output_dim": self.output_dim,
            "learning_rate": self.learning_rate,
            "dropout_rate": self.dropout_rate,
            "batch_size": self.batch_size,
            "max_epochs": self.max_epochs
        }

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)
        return self
    
window_size = 32  # same as sequence_length
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
hidden_dim = 63
num_layers = 4
output_dim = 1
learning_rate = 0.000689
dropout_rate = 0.170971

model = SKLearnFFNetwork(
    input_dim=input_dim,
    sequence_length=window_size,
    hidden_dim=hidden_dim,
    num_layers=num_layers,
    output_dim=output_dim,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
    batch_size=32,
    max_epochs=300
)

# Fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

X_test_with_history = pd.concat([X_train.iloc[-window_size:], X_test])
predictions = model.predict(X_test_with_history)

# Trim predictions to match original test set length
predictions = predictions[-len(X_test):]

# plot point pred
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
plt.plot(y_train)
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.plot(y_test.index ,predictions)
plt.ylabel("Hourly demand (GW)")
plt.legend(["Training data", "Test data"])
plt.show()


#### MAPIE process and code updates
class BlockBootstrap(_BaseKFold):
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_resamplings: int = 30,
        n_blocks: int = 10,
        window_size: int = 32,
        test_size: int = 91,
        random_state: Optional[Union[int, np.random.RandomState]] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.n_resamplings = n_resamplings
        self.n_blocks = n_blocks
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.test_size = test_size
        self.random_state = random_state

    def split(
        self, X: NDArray, y: Optional[NDArray] = None, groups: Optional[NDArray] = None
    ) -> Generator[Tuple[NDArray, NDArray], None, None]:
        n = len(X)
        train_size = n - self.test_size
        block_size = train_size // self.n_blocks

        random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)

        for _ in range(self.n_resamplings):
            # Create blocks
            block_starts = random_state.choice(range(train_size - block_size + 1), size=self.n_blocks, replace=True)
            train_indices = np.concatenate([np.arange(start, start + block_size) for start in block_starts])
            train_indices = np.unique(train_indices)

            # Ensure last window_size elements of training set are included
            train_indices = np.unique(np.concatenate([train_indices, np.arange(train_size - self.window_size, train_size)]))

            # Create test indices
            test_indices = np.arange(train_size, n)

            yield train_indices, test_indices

    def get_n_splits(self, X: Optional[NDArray] = None, y: Optional[NDArray] = None, groups: Optional[NDArray] = None) -> int:
        return self.n_resamplings
    

from mapie.regression import MapieTimeSeriesRegressor
from mapie.metrics import regression_coverage_score, regression_mean_width_score, coverage_width_based

alpha = 0.05
gap = 1
window_size = 32
test_size = 91

cv_mapiets = BlockBootstrap(
    n_resamplings=10,
    n_blocks=10,
    #overlapping=False,
    window_size=window_size,
    test_size=test_size,
    random_state=59
)

mapie_enbpi = MapieTimeSeriesRegressor(
    model, method="enbpi", cv=cv_mapiets, agg_function="mean", n_jobs=-1
)

# For EnbPI
mapie_enbpi = mapie_enbpi.fit(X_train, y_train)
#del([y_pred_enbpi_npfit,y_pis_enbpi_npfit])

X_test_with_history = pd.concat([X_train.iloc[-window_size:], X_test])

y_pred_raw , y_pis_raw = mapie_enbpi.predict(
    X_test_with_history, alpha=alpha, ensemble=True, optimize_beta=True,
    allow_infinite_bounds=True
)
# trim to match y_test
y_pred = y_pred_raw[-test_size:]
y_pis = y_pis_raw[-test_size:]

valid_pred_indices = ~np.isnan(y_pred)
y_pred = y_pred[valid_pred_indices]
y_pis = y_pis[valid_pred_indices]

width_enbpi = regression_mean_width_score(
    y_pis[:, 0, 0], y_pis[:, 1, 0]
)

cwc_enbpi = coverage_width_based(
    y_test, y_pis[:, 0, 0],
    y_pis[:, 1, 0],
    eta=10,
    alpha=0.05
)

# Print results
print(f"Coverage: {coverage_enbpi}")
print(f"Mean Width: {width_enbpi}")
print(f"CWC: {cwc_enbpi}")

# Extract dates for test set
train_dates = date_col[:len(y_train)]
test_dates = date_col[-len(y_test):]

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
#plt.plot(train_dates, y_train, label='Actual', color='black', linewidth=1.5) # un comment to see whole ts length
plt.plot(test_dates, y_test, label='Actual', color='blue', linewidth=1.5)
plt.plot(test_dates, predictions, label='Predictions', color='purple', linestyle='--', linewidth=1.5)
plt.fill_between(test_dates, y_pis[:, 0, 0], y_pis[:, 1, 0], color='purple', alpha=0.3, label='Prediction Interval')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.title('Actual vs Predictions with Conformal Prediction Intervals')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

I also added this code to the linked github issue above.

might have to put this through a LLM to explain fully. If there is interest let me know. I can also add the weighted code.
